# Conversão de chamada de fragment de Java para Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, conversão

Estou criando um app que terá uma activity principal e alguns fragments intercalados, nesse caso estou tentando lançar um fragment_main porém não consigo frazer esse código Java virar código Koltin:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
UsuarioCadFragment fragment = new UsuarioCadFragment();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

esse código deve ser chamado logo na criação da activity principal, porém em kotlin.

Comment: Qual o código Kotlin que desenvolveu até ao momento ? Coloque-o na pergunta também

Answer (score 0):

O método `getFragmentManager()` está deprecated a partir da API level 28. Recomenda-se utilizar o método `getSupportFragmentManager()` no lugar dele, ou, usando property access syntax do kotlin, você pode simplesmente acessá-lo como `supportFragmentManager`.

Uma forma de fazer isso que você está tentando fazer é a seguinte:

```
val tx = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
tx.replace(R.id.fragment_container, UsuarioCadFragment())
tx.commit()
```